# How to include all files from a directory in shell script (/etc/init.d/iptables in this case)

Tags: linux, unix, bash, iptables, shell

I have an `/etc/init.d/iptables start|stop|restart` script on different ubuntu servers (which is a normal shell script)

For each new service I have to edit and insert a line to open a port. This leads to many different versions of the init.d script on different machines.

Is it possible to automatically include let's say all files in `/etc/iptables/include.d/` ?

The target is that there should only a line in the *start* function of /etc/init.d/iptables like

```
include /etc/iptables/include.d/*
```

And after an additional file in `/etc/iptables/include.d/` I'd simply say

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

**Edit:** As Saurabh pointed out this can lead to problems when commands need a certain order. An advanced setup could have different directories like:

```
/etc/iptables/include01.d/
/etc/iptables/include02.d/
/etc/iptables/include03.d/
```

and including them like this:

```
    include /etc/iptables/include01.d/*
    ... maybe some code goes here in the main file...
    include /etc/iptables/include02.d/*
    include /etc/iptables/include03.d/*
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following line to your init.d script.

```
run-parts --report /etc/iptables/include.d
```

It will run everything in the directory as a shell script (need to be executable).

If you you only want to execute files that ends with .port you could use something
like:

```
run-parts --regex '\.port$' /etc/iptables/include.d/
```

If you want to make sure the order is correct you can name the files:

```
10_web.port
20_ssh.port
etc..
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in /etc/iptables/include.d/*
 . $f
done
```

note space between dot and %f

Saurabh is right - this will not necessary work as you intend, but use some naming convention eg 10-xxx, 20-yyy and so on and it might be manageable.

Comment: i think this is great, because i do not rely on an external command (run-parts)

Comment: will the order of the files when numbered 10-xxx, 20-yyy be respected automatically by the `for f in` ?

Comment: @matnagel - should be. if you have any doubts, replace  /etc/iptables/include.d/* with `ls -1  /etc/iptables/include.d/*.extension` - with ls you can control sorting criteria, default one is by name. notice special quote symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can define simple function in bash:

```
function include() {
    for FILE in $( find "$1" -type f -print | sort )
    do
        source $FILE
    done
}
```

and then:

```
include some_dir/*
```

or even:

```
include some_dir/*.conf
```

Comment: this is even better than pQd's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider building the iptables script from template files, one of which would be the original iptables script. create a script which will read your template files in the relevant directories and create a new iptables script from them. That way when you need to make changes you do so in the templates and just rerun your script generator.

Using this method you could even get fancy and place markers in the base template which can be used to signal when to include files from specific directories in your template tree.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can include files in iptables configuration. The choice makes sense as firewall rules depend a lot on order in which they are written. If we just include files in folder, iptables wont know which rules to put first and which later.

Comment: this is a good point. thank you for pointing this out. i am updating the question to use several include.d directories, so I can give them an order. I have many services that do not depend on each other and the setup would still make sense in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

To well behave with empty dir `include.d/` you can do:

```
for f in /etc/iptables/include.d/*; do
  [[ -e "${f}" ]] && . "${f}"
done
```